# URL not loading when publishing first github page

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I am trying to start a Github website. I followed the directions on their start page (https://pages.github.com/), made sure my repo had the right username, and everything. I made the index.html file as well, very simple, but based on their recommendations.

And it seemed to push just fine. However, when I go to access the site (https://jjkellogg.github.io) as mentioned in the pages start page, I receive a 404 error message:

"404
File not found
The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.
Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages."

I can see the files on the main repo site, https://github.com/jjkellogg/jjkellogg.github.io. Can anyone help clue me in to what I have done wrong/might be missing?

Comment: Have you tried not having the filename in ALL CAPS?

Comment: agree with @jonrsharpe  . Likely the capitalization of filename and extension that is breaking it.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @jonrsharpe and @webmite; the file is lowercase on my desktop, and must have been changed when it got pushed?

Answer (score 0):

Github page servers are case sensitives. `A` and `a` are not the same characters.

By default, it looks for an **index.html**. Although your https://jjkellogg.github.io/INDEX.HTML works, it is not served as a default page.

Renaming your **INDEX.HTML** to **index.html** will solve your problem.